# In JavaScript, eval(010) returns 8

Tags: javascript

If I use the code:

```
string = '010';
write = eval(string);
document.write(write)
```

I get 8 written on the page. Why?
This happens even if 010 isn't a string.

Comment: `var i = 010;` gives you 8 too. Has nothing to do with `eval`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because 010 is parsed as octal. Javascript treats a leading zero as indicating that the value is in base 8.

Similarly, 0x10 would give you 16, being parsed in hex.

If you want to parse a string using a specified base, use parseInt:

```
parseInt('010', 8); // returns 8.
parseInt('010',10); // returns 10.
parseInt('010',16); // returns 16.
```

Comment: See http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm for more information.

Comment: You can also override the default `parseInt()` behavior so that it no longer does this, as described here:  http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/394

Answer (score 4):

Prefixing a number with an `0` means it's [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), i.e. base 8. Similar to prefixing with `0x` for hexadecimal numbers (base 16).

Use the second argument of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to force a base:

```
> parseInt('010')
8
> parseInt('010', 10)
10
```

Comment: +1 for providing a solution. Alternatively you can use unary `+`.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot man. Interesting that the parseInt('010',10) trick won't work if the 010 isn't a string.

Comment: That's because if the 010 isn't a string, then it gets parsed as a numeric literal BEFORE being passed to parseInt as an argument.

Comment: @The Awesome one. That's because `010` is already the number `8` when it's given to `parseInt`; `parseInt` can't distinguish whether its argument was `010`, `8`, `4+4`, or `parseInt("010")`

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to output the string `010` to the document, you can wrap the value in quotation marks:

```
var octal = eval('"010"');
typeof octal; // "string"
```

If you want to parse an integer or understand octals, read the other answers.