# How to convert a number 010 to a string "010"

Tags: javascript

While executing some random expressions in console, I just found that

`010 + ""` returning `8`  (even 011,0100.. are returning results by considering octal number system)

What would I have to do if I want to convert a number `010` to a string `"010"`? Not only for `010` but for every similar numbers. I managed to find a kind of similar explanation for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718102/in-javascript-eval010-returns-8). But that is not explaining how to convert it into a exact string version.

Comment: Have you tried `toString` function

Comment: hmm `number.toString()` ?

Comment: @BipBip , Jay : "+" will basically do `.toString()` internally when it meets a string. `010 + ""` is equal to `(010).toString()` Do a quick test in your console.

Comment: You should convert you number to string and manipulate it as a string. num.toString() should work for you.

Comment: Assuming first it converts the number to string because is in binary format it converts it to`(010.toString() = 8)`.

Comment: may b duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718102/in-javascript-eval010-returns-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript `010` is octal literal and converts to 8 in decimal literal. In fact, you should avoid it, as strict mode disallows to use it.

There is no way to distinguish between octal and decimal notation other than parsing function body string :)

Answer (score 6):

Get a string first by invoking the `toString()` method with the base number which is `8` in this case

```
Number(010).toString(8); //outputs "10"
```

it works without wrapping in Number too,

```
010.toString(8); //outputs "10"
```

use this method to padd 0's if you know the length of original number

```
function pad(n,digits){return n<Math.pow(10, digits) ? '0'+n : n}
```

so

```
pad(Number(010).toString(8),3); //3 is the number of digits
```

Comment: no need (in my testing), to wrap in `Number()`: `010.toString(8)`.

Comment: also, I'm not sure that padding will work with the OP input of `010`.

Comment: @DavinTryon made the changes to pass the number of digits, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
"0" + (010).toString(8)  // "010"
"0" + (0111).toString(8) // "0111"
```

And a more general solution:

```
function toStringOctal(number) {
  return "0" + number.toString(8);
}

toStringOctal(010) // return "010"
```

But notice that in **strict mode** octal notations `0<number>` are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 10;
var string = "0" + num.toString();
console.log(string);//gives you "010"
```

As mentioned in the comments to this post, it won't convert 010 directly, but will build a string. Not the most elegant solution.

Comment: what about 0111/010001 etc?

Comment: Just do the same but with the new numbers, so `var num = 111` or `var num = 10001`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to convert multiple similar numbers into strings, you could also build a simple function that will do the work when called:

```
function convertSomething(number) {
    var string = "" + number;
    return string
}
```

Then you can just call your conversion function whenever you need it.