# How to convert a binary(input) to string(output) by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, binary

For example : 
input:0010 [number]
output: 0010 [string]

I know the `0010` in JavaScript will be regarded as octal, so is it possible to code a function to convert it to string? The similar questions on stackoverflow had said how to convert known number of the leading zero input , but I haven't found any solution for unknown zero number input.

Similar questions :

- [How to convert a number 010 to a string “010”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360380/how-to-convert-a-number-010-to-a-string-010)
- [In JavaScript, eval(010) returns 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718102/in-javascript-eval010-returns-8)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
var bin = 1111;
var dec = parseInt(bin, 2);
var tostr= dec.toString(2)
```

Comment: This also can not work . Because input a number with leading zero will be treated octal . Try the `0111` ,will got  `NaN`

Comment: In that case, you could convert using parseInt('0111')

Answer (score 0):

If you know the wanted size for your output string, you can do this :

```
function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
 return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

var outputString = pad(0010.toString(8),4); // 4 is the length of your output string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var bin = 1111;
 var str = bin + '';
 console.log(str)

 // Pls try  working perfectly
```

Comment: -1: this is not a solution, because `var bin` is the number 'elevenhundredandeleven', not the binary representation for 15 as you implicitly claim it to be.