# Wierd Javascript addition behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, binary, console

Why `2 + 10 = 12` and `2 + 010 = 10`? I tried this on console of *Google Chrome v 51.0* and *IE 8* only to get the same results. Maybe this is feature of Javascript.
 Somebody please help me understand the logic behind it and what possible good it can serve?

Comment: Best to `'use strict'` otherwise `0` in front of a number makes an octal.

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718102/in-javascript-eval010-returns-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime JavaScript treats numbers *exactly* as you specify them, other times it tries to 'interpret' the number.

In this case, JavaScript is interpreting the number.

The leading zero means that the number is octal -- base 8 -- where the digits go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

So.. 010 (octal) == 8 (decimal)

```
2 + 010
2 + 8
10
```

If you are dealing with numbers from an outside source, you can use `parseInt`

```
2 + parseInt("010", 10);
```

Note: The `,10` is also important to force that number to be translated as base 10.  In ES3 (and I believe 5) you may get different results without it, depending upon the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Its not binary, the 0 at the start makes it octal, and octal 010 == 8

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Answer (score 2):

`0` before a number tells javascript to interpret the number as octal. So `10` in octal means `8` in decimal and `8 + 2` is `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with leading 0 are considered as octal numbers. That is why 010 is interpreted as 8 hence you get 10 as sum of **2 + 010**. This happens with python as well.

Answer (score 1):

`10` is equal to `8` in octal and the first zero tells javascript to interpret that as an octal number. So when `2 + 010` is executed, at first `010` is translated into `8` and then it is added to the `2` to give `10`.